# Unparseable date after upgrading/downgrading Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

So, finally trying to come up from the stone age, upgraded 1.514 to 1.644 without realizing all slaves need to be running Java 1.7 as well. So I install Java 7 on my master, swap .war files to run 1.644 and start it up. Slaves don't come up due to the aforementioned Java req. After stopping Jenkins and removing Java 1.7, I swap back to the 1.514 .war and start Jenkins back up. Now my build history is gone from all jobs with this error in the log:

```
WARNING: could not load /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/[job name removed]/builds/312 hudson.util.IOException2: Invalid directory name /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/YYMM Check and Build/builds/312 at hudson.model.Run.parseTimestampFromBuildDir(Run.java:354)

...

Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "312" at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:354) at hudson.model.Run.parseTimestampFromBuildDir(Run.java:352) ... 155 more
```

The only things I can find online relate to issues that were fixed pre-1.514. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Installed the latest version that works with Java 1.6: 1.607, and that fixed the issue as soon as it started up.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are likely related the change to the build directory naming, see [JENKINS-24380+Migration](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JENKINS-24380+Migration).

> In case you want to downgrade, there is an “unmigrate” script provided to reverse the migration of $JENKINS_HOME. To do this:
>
> 1. Start Jenkins ≥1.597.
> 2. Visit http://server/jenkins/JENKINS-24380/ and copy the unmigration instruction.
> 3. Shut down Jenkins completely.
> 4. Run the command as instructed by the step above.
> 5. Start Jenkins <1.597 with the same $JENKINS_HOME.